# Bubble sort algorithm solution

Tags: c, algorithm, bubble-sort

I am Trying to sort an array using buble sort algorithm

```
type here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//bubble sort algorithm.
int main()
{
    int temp[]={5,3,4,7,8,1};
    int n=6;
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if (temp[j] > temp[j+1])
            {
                int swap = temp[j];
                temp[j] = temp[j+1];
                temp[j+1] = swap;
            }

        }
        printf("%i",temp[i]);
    }

}
```

I was expecting this output,

> 134578
> but produced this
> 34157
> what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Your printing doesn't print `array[n-1]`.  Separate the sorting and the printing.

Answer (score 2):

Correct code is below. You are printing array in between. After sorting we need to print it to get proper result

```
#include <stdio.h>
//bubble sort algorithm.
int main()
{
    int temp[]={5,3,4,7,8,1};
    int n=6;
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if (temp[j] > temp[j+1])
            {
                int swap = temp[j];
                temp[j] = temp[j+1];
                temp[j+1] = swap;
            }

        }
       
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%i",temp[i]);
    }
}
```